# Batch file to rename specific files, exclude specific files in multiple folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-rename

Good Day,

I have a folder that contains folders of movies on it. in each folder, there is the video files, .srt for subtitles, jpg for posters and lastly I included Trailers for the said movie.

I want a batch file that will:

1. Rename all my ".mp4 .mkv .avi" movie files as well as ".srt" into its folder name (since I rename my Folders like this "Fight Club (1999)[1080p], so the movie file and .srt will be of same name, except of course it's extension).
2. Rename all *.jpeg *.jpg *.png to "poster.jpg or poster.png".
3. Rename all Trailer files to just "Trailer.mp4. I put Trailers for each of the movies, whenever you download one, I want to remove messy filenames like "---Fight Club - #TBT Trailer - 20th Century FOX" and just turn it into "Trailers.mp4.
4. Exclude renaming those that already have the "Trailer" filename.

Each of the folder name will look like this:
Fight Club (1999)[1080p].mp4, Fight Club (1999)[1080p].srt, Fight Club (1999)[1080p].nfo, poster.jpg, Trailer.mp4.

I made this but I encountered these:

1. I can't rename the messy Trailer file into just "Trailer.mp4".
2. Can't skip to rename the "Trailer.mkv", it renames to the folder name.

Help please, thanks a lot.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


cd /D "%~DP0"
echo BASE FOLDER: %cd%
set n=0
for /D %%a in (*) do (
set /A n+=1
cd "%%a"
echo ==================================================================
echo Processing folder: %%a
set movieName=%%~a

except (*Trailer.mp4)
except (*Trailer.mkv)

for %%b in (*.avi *.mp4 *.mkv) do (
   ren "%%~b" "!movieName!%%~Xb"
   echo Movie file "%%b" renamed to "!movieName!%%~Xb"


for %%b in (*.srt *.sub *.ass *.ssa *.idx) do (
   ren "%%~b" "!movieName!%%~Xb"
   echo File "%%b" renamed to "!movieName!%%~Xb"
)

for %%b in (*.jpeg *.jpg *.png) do (
   ren "%%~b" "!poster.jpg"
echo File "%%b" renamed to "!poster.jpg~Xb"
)

for fname in *Trailer; do
   newname=`echo "$fname" | sed 's/Trailer/Trailer/g'`
   sed 's/Trailer/Trailer/g' "$fname" >"$newname"
done

cd ..

)
echo ==================================================================
```

Comment: Use a better editor (like [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) ) to properly indent the code. The first for has no closing parenthesis. The last for is unclear bash code. sed substitite a word with itself twice?

Comment: To find trailers you can use patterns like `*Trailer*.avi`, `*Trailer*.mp4`, `*Trailer*.mkv`, supposing they all have the word `Trailer` in their file names; anyway, you should first search for them and rename them to `Trailer.*`; then you can handle the movie files, which are all those *not* named `Trailer.*`; place `if /I not "%%~nb"=="Trailer" ( ... )` into the first loop to exclude the already renamed files `Trailer.*`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /D "%~dp0"
echo BASE FOLDER: %cd%
set n=0
for /D %%a in (*) do (
    set /A n+=1
    PushD "%%a"
    echo ==================================================================
    echo Processing folder: %%a
    set "movieName=%%~a"

    rem except (*Trailer.mp4),except (*Trailer.mkv)
    for /f "delims=" %%b in (
      'dir /B *.avi *.mp4 *.mkv ^|findstr /i /v "Trailer" '
    ) do (
       ren "%%~b" "!movieName!%%~Xb" && ^
       echo Movie file "%%b" renamed to "!movieName!%%~Xb"
    )

    for %%b in (*.srt *.sub *.ass *.ssa *.idx) do (
       ren "%%~b" "!movieName!%%~Xb"&& ^
       echo File "%%b" renamed to "!movieName!%%~Xb"
    )

    for %%b in (*.jpeg *.jpg *.png) do (
        ren "%%~b" "poster%%~xb" && ^
        echo File "%%b" renamed to "poster%%~xb"
    )

    for /f "delims=" %%b in (
      'dir /B "*trailer*" '
    ) do (
       ren "%%~b" "Trailer%%~Xb" && ^
       echo Movie file "%%b" renamed to "Trailer%%~Xb"
    )
    PopD
)
echo ==================================================================
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. it is working but, I tried a scenario wherein there a 2 files having "trailer" on its filename with different file extension, it was able to do as intended, but renamed the second "trailer" as that of the folder name, which was the movie name. Can you please edit the batch file so that, in cases like it, both files (the mkv and mp4) versions of "trailers" are renamed as such and not be named after folder name... Thank you so much for positive response.

Comment: In the first for the `findstr /v` only excluded files with trailing `Trailer` a literal dot and an extension starting with m, changed. Any file including `Trailer` at any position is now excluded and lateron shortened to only Trailer.ext

Comment: Thank you very much.... now I have a very powerful renaming tool in hand... Bless you Brother. May you have a great day...

Comment: Well, the preferred way to get thanked is to accept an answer and/or voting up.